# get parent entry in hierachy

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm getting a hierarchy in the following structure (table: hierarchy):

[image]

Each entry has an Id and a level number. The example database can be downloaded here https://easyupload.io/mtlb1z or the table definition here https://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IUCZE

The parent id (which I try to get) is the first id which is on the level below (minus one).

E.g. for Id 10 on level 3 the next lower level (= level 2) has the Id 9. For id 8 on level 2 the corresponding parent (level 1) has the id 1.

I am looking for an UPDATE query which updates each entry once:

```
UPDATE hierarchy 
SET parent = (SELECT id
              FROM hierarchy as hierarchy_1
              WHERE hierarchy.id>hierarchy_1.id AND hierarchy_1.level=hierarchy.level-1)
```

Can anybody please help me to get the corresponding parent id for each entry?

Update:
With the following SELECT query I get the parent ids:

```
SELECT hierarchy.id, MAX(db1.parent) AS parent
FROM (
        SELECT hierarchy.id, hierarchy_1.id AS parent
        FROM hierarchy, hierarchy AS hierarchy_1
        WHERE hierarchy_1.level=[hierarchy].[level]-1 AND hierarchy_1.id<[hierarchy].[id]
) as db1
GROUP BY hierarchy.id
```

But how can I swap this query in to a working UPDATE query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the sub query returns one value only.
So you can use `TOP 1` and sort the result regarding the one you want:

```
UPDATE hierarchy 
SET parent = (SELECT TOP 1 hierarchy_1.id
              FROM hierarchy as hierarchy_1
              WHERE hierarchy_1.id < hierarchy.id
              AND hierarchy_1.level < hierarchy.level
              ORDER BY hierarchy_1.level DESC, hierarchy_1.id DESC )
```

As a side note, you also had a typo here, both compare a field of `hierarchy_1`: `hierarchy_1.level=hierarchy_1.level-1`

Comment: Thanks for the advice with the typo. I still get the error message "Operation must use an updateable query"

Comment: I also changed the query. It is working well here. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes I tried your code, but I still get the error message :-(

Comment: Maybe a problem with primary key? I made one on the field `id`.

Comment: I set up the id as primary key as well but both ways doesn't work. Here is my former table definition -> https://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IUCZE

Comment: Please add the definition to your original question.

Comment: I added the structure and the database for download

Comment: Can I handover the id and level in DMAX like in this Query: UPDATE hierarchy AS Master SET Master.parent = DMAX("id","hierarchy","hierarchy.id<Master.id AND hierarchy.level=Master.level-1")

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the best way to solve it:

```
UPDATE hierarchy SET parent = DMAX("id","hierarchy","hierarchy.id<" & hierarchy.id & " AND hierarchy.level=" & hierarchy.level-1 & "")
```